# React JS Signin with Linked in redirecting to 404 page on hosted website but not on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0

I have a simple react js application that I'm trying to implement Signin with LinkedIn. I have it all working on my localhost, but when I push the app online the pop up appears, I login, then it goes to a 404 redirect page with the token in the URL.

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkedin-login-oauth2 as my base template and have treied using both approaches (hooks and props) but both work on localhost and not online.

I have triple checked my "Authorized redirect URLs for your app" in LinkedIn developer center and they are correct.

This is my App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import { LinkedInCallback } from "react-linkedin-login-oauth2";
import LinkedInPage from "./LoginPage";

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title="Push"
  })

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/linkedin" element={<LinkedInCallback />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<LinkedInPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my LoginPage

```
                      import React, { useState } from "react";
import { LinkedIn } from "react-linkedin-login-oauth2";
import linkedin from "react-linkedin-login-oauth2/assets/linkedin.png";
import { Button, Card, Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

function LoginPage() {
  const [name, setName] = useState()
  const [email, setEmail] = useState()

  const [code, setCode] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  return (
    <Container className="">
                    <LinkedIn
                      clientId="86f2j1y6awao41"
                      redirectUri={`${window.location.origin}/linkedin`}
                      onSuccess={(code) => {
                        console.log(code);
                      }}
                      onError={(error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                      }}
                    >
                      {({ linkedInLogin }) => (
                        <img
                          onClick={linkedInLogin}
                          src={linkedin}
                          alt="Sign in with Linked In"
                          style={{ maxWidth: '180px', cursor: 'pointer' }}
                        />
                      )}
                    </LinkedIn>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

And this is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "linkedin-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-linkedin-login-oauth2": "^2.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the way hostinger manages redirects.

Solution was to update the .htaccess file to always navigate back to index.html for unknown routes. This way the routing handles it properly.